# Not grouping through latest dates

Tags: sql, database, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables as follows:

**BarcodeGroupMap**

[image]

**CategoryMaster**

[image]

**ProductMaster:**

[image]

From these 3 tables i have made following query:

```
select bgm.BarcodeItem,
cm.CategoryID,cm.CategoryName,pm.ProductName,pm.ProductID,bgm.EffectFrom,bgm.Groups
from BarcodeGroupMap bgm,CategoryMaster cm,ProductMaster pm where
bgm.ProductID=pm.ProductID  and bgm.categoryID=cm.CategoryID
```

This query results into following:

[image]

Now, as we can see in query result barcode is repeating,

I just wanted to show one barcode once, according to Its latest **Createddate** from **Barcodegroupmap** table.

For this i made following query :

```
select bgm.BarcodeItem,
cm.CategoryID,cm.CategoryName,pm.ProductName,pm.ProductID,bgm.EffectFrom,bgm.Groups
from BarcodeGroupMap bgm,CategoryMaster cm,ProductMaster pm where
bgm.ProductID=pm.ProductID  and bgm.categoryID=cm.CategoryID and
bgm.BarcodeItem= select BarcodeItem from  BarcodeGroupMap bm1  where
CreatedDate=  (select top 1 CreatedDate from  BarcodeGroupMap bm2  
)order by bm1.BarcodeItem
```

But its not giving me correct result.

Please help me.

I just want to display one barcode item only one time according to its latested createddate in Barcodegroupmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no way of actually trying this query, because I do not have relevant tables and data, but this should get you started:

```
SELECT BarcodeItem, temp.CategoryID, cm.CategoryName, temp.ProductID, pm.ProductName, EffectFrom FROM ( 
  SELECT BarcodeItem, CategoryID, ProductID, CONVERT(date, EffectFrom) as EffectFrom,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY BarcodeItem ORDER BY EffectFrom DESC) dest_rank
    FROM BarcodeGroupMap
  ) temp
  inner join CategoryMaster cm on cm.CategoryID = temp.CategoryID
  inner join ProductMaster pm on pm.ProductID = temp.ProductID
  where temp.dest_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables no?

```
SELECT bgm.BarcodeItem,
cm.CategoryID,cm.CategoryName,pm.ProductName,pm.ProductID,bgm.EffectFrom,bgm.Groups
from BarcodeGroupMap bgm
INNER JOIN CategoryMaster cm on bgm.categoryID=cm.CategoryID
INNER JOIN ProductMaster pm ON bgm.ProductID=pm.ProductID 
WHERE bgm.CreatedDate = (select top 1 CreatedDate from  BarcodeGroupMap bm2  
WHERE bgm.BarcodeItem = bm2.BarcodeItem ORDER BY CreatedDate  desc) order by bgm.BarcodeItem
```

If you do not want to join

```
select bgm.BarcodeItem,
cm.CategoryID,cm.CategoryName,pm.ProductName,pm.ProductID,bgm.EffectFrom,bgm.Groups
from BarcodeGroupMap bgm,CategoryMaster cm,ProductMaster pm where
bgm.ProductID=pm.ProductID  and bgm.categoryID=cm.CategoryID and
where bgm.CreatedDate=  (select top 1 CreatedDate from  BarcodeGroupMap bm2  
WHERE bgm.BarcodeItem = bm2.BarcodeItem ORDER BY CreatedDate  desc) order by bm1.BarcodeItem
```